# How to increase the efficiency of edge detection to count the number of rocks of different sizes on a conveyor belt

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, edge-detection

**Problem Statement:**

I need to write a code to most closely approximate the number of rocks that fall within a speficied size range. (Eg 30-40mm, 40-50mm, 50-60mm, 60mm+)

I have written a code to do the same but it is not as effective in doing that. Steps that I have followed

1. Reducing the size of the image
2. Converting to grayscale
3. Gaussian blurring
4. Thresholding to get rid of completely dark regions
5. Then joining the blurred image with the thresholded image using cv2.bitwise_and()
6. Finding and drawing contours whose are is > 100.

After these steps, there is still an important issue that I am not able to get closed contours around the rocks so that I can find the area and major and minor axes so that I can find the sizes of the rocks.

**Case 1**

Original Image [1] 
Output Image with contours drawn (https://i.stack.imgur.com/DebT5.jpg) 
The total number of objects detected = 162

**Case 2**

Original Image (https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhrFu.jpg)
Output Image with contors drawn (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jre5A.jpg) 
The total number of object detected = 149

**How can I improve the accuracy of my code?**

This is my code so far.

````
    import cv2
    import numpy as np
    import csv

    # Read the image
    img = cv2.imread("Images/24.jpg")

    #percent by which the image is resized
    scale_percent = 75

    #calculate the 90 percent of original dimensions
    width = int(img.shape[2] * scale_percent / 100)
    height = int(img.shape[0] * scale_percent / 100)
    
    # dsize
    dsize = (width, height)

    # resize image
    original = cv2.resize(img, dsize)

    cv2.imshow("Original", original)
    cv2.waitKey(0)

    # Convert the image to grayscale
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(original, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Apply Gaussian Blur to reduce noise
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)

    # threshold the image by setting all pixel values less than 225
    # to 255 (white; foreground) and all pixel values >= 225 to 255
    # (black; background), thereby segmenting the image
    thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 50, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[2]

    cv2.imshow("thresh", thresh)
    cv2.waitKey(0)

    #Removing noise from the image

    #define kernel size  
    #kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
    #mask = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
    #mask = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
    mask = cv2.dilate(thresh, None, iterations=1)
    cv2.imshow("Noise Removal", mask)
    cv2.waitKey(0)

    # joining the original image and the noise reduced image
    segmented_img = cv2.bitwise_and(blur, blur, mask=mask)

    cv2.imshow("segmented", segmented_img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)

    #edge detection in the segmented image
    edged_2 = cv2.Canny(segmented_img, 120, 180)

    cv2.imshow("Canny on segmented image", edged_2)
    cv2.waitKey(0)

    # find contours (i.e., outlines) of the foreground objects in the
    # thresholded image
    cnts = cv2.findContours(edged_2.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    #cnts = cnts[0] if imutils.is_cv2() else cnts[2]
    cnts = cnts[0]
    output = original.copy()
    objects_number = 0
    major_axis = 0
    minor_axis = 0
    results = []
     
    for c in cnts:

        area = cv2.contourArea(c)        
            
        print("The area is ", area)
        if (area >=100):
            ellipse = cv2.fitEllipse(c)
            major_axis = round(max(ellipse[2]),2)
            minor_axis = round(min(ellipse[2]),2)
            
            results.append([area, major_axis, minor_axis])
            objects_number = objects_number+1
        # draw each contour on the output image with a 3px thick purple
        # outline, then display the output contours one at a time
            cv2.drawContours(output, [c], -1, (240, 0, 159), 3)

    print("Total number of objects detected =", objects_number)

    # Open a new CSV file for writing
    with open('results.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        
        # Write the header row
        writer.writerow(['Contour area', 'Major axis', 'Minor axis'])
        
        # Write the results for each contour
        for row in results:
            writer.writers(row)

    print ("The total number of objects =", objects_number)
    cv2.imshow("Contours", output)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows() ```
 


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCupv.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qlq5.jpg
````

Comment: add code or inline images instead of images url.

Comment: I do not have enough reputation points to add inline images.